# Error when using pschart with LaTeX

Tags: incompatibility, pstricks-add

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{
   unit=4cm,
   nodesepA=5pt,
   nodesepB=-5pt
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(9,9)
   \psChart[
     userColor={blue!60,yellow!60,green!60,red!60},
     chartNodeO=1.25,
     shadow=true,
     shadowsize=5pt
   ]{1082, 1572, 2336, 643}{}{}
   \rput(psChartI1){\SI{1082}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
   \nput{0}{psChartO1}{Rism. med}
   \rput(psChartI2){\SI{1572}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
   \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Rism. uden}
   \rput(psChartI3){\SI{2336}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
   \nput{270}{psChartO3}{Skov m.m.}
   \rput(psChartI4){\SI{643}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO4}{psChart4}
   \nput{0}{psChartO4}{Andet}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I make it compilable using `latex`? (If I use `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape`, everything is fine.)

**Update**

The following works when using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{
   unit=4cm,
   nodesepA=5pt,
   nodesepB=-5pt
 }
\fbox{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-0.98,-1.21)(1.44,1.17)
   \psChart[
     userColor={blue!60,yellow!60,green!60,red!60},
     chartNodeO=1.25,
     shadow=true,
     shadowsize=5pt
   ]{1082, 1572, 2336, 643}{}{}
   \rput(psChartI1){\SI{1082}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
   \nput{0}{psChartO1}{Rism. med}
   \rput(psChartI2){\SI{1572}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
   \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Rism. uden}
   \rput(psChartI3){\SI{2336}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
   \nput{270}{psChartO3}{Skov m.m.}
   \rput(psChartI4){\SI{643}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO4}{psChart4}
   \nput{0}{psChartO4}{Andet}
  \end{pspicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\fbox` is used to find the correct coordinates for the bounding box.

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` is a compatibility layer to make sone pstricks functionality available in pdftex, I assume you just don't want that package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. Do you know you to make the code compile using `latex`?

Comment: as I said, just remove `auto-pst-pdf,` and use latex and dvips then ps2pdf or distliier or whatever to get pdf.

Comment: you get `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 474.29918pt on input line 35.`
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly (regarding the warning). Furthermore, no pie chart diagram is drawn (or more specificlly, I get a DVI file that I can't open).

Comment: OH Ok it runs without error just those warnings and the final page is white, I assume it is printing off page but the internal pdfcrop call used by the auto-pst-pdf gets things back. My pstricks is a bit rusty to say how to adjust the coordinates to bring it back

Comment: see my edited answer for using `(9,9)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `auto-pst-pdf` crops by default the created image the reason why it is not important to have the correct bounding box specified by the `pspicture` environment. The command `\psset` is used *before* `pspicture` and so not taken into account for `auto-pst-pdf`.

When using `latex` with `auto-pst-pdf` all settings before `pspicture` are valid and you'll get an image which is (4*9,4*9) which is too big. It is moved to the next page but `auto-pst-pdf` uses only the first page which is empty. Put the settings of `\psset` into the `pspicture` environment or put *all* into an environment `postscript`.

If you want to use the `(9,9)` bounding box then use

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(9,9)
  \rput(4.5,4.5){%
   \psset{unit=4cm,nodesepA=5pt,nodesepB=-5pt}
   \psChart[
    [ ... ] 
   \nput{0}{psChartO4}{Andet}}% end of \rput
  \end{pspicture}
[ ... ]
```

Comment: Nice explanation, Herbert!

Comment: Great, regrading the `(9,9)` bounding box!

Answer (score 4):

By default it prints off page, but if you change the units from 4cm to 2cm you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{
   unit=2cm,%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   nodesepA=5pt,
   nodesepB=-5pt
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(9,9)
   \psChart[
     userColor={blue!60,yellow!60,green!60,red!60},
     chartNodeO=1.25,
     shadow=true,
     shadowsize=5pt
   ]{1082, 1572, 2336, 643}{}{}
   \rput(psChartI1){\SI{1082}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
   \nput{0}{psChartO1}{Rism. med}
   \rput(psChartI2){\SI{1572}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
   \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Rism. uden}
   \rput(psChartI3){\SI{2336}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
   \nput{270}{psChartO3}{Skov m.m.}
   \rput(psChartI4){\SI{643}{\square\km}}
   \ncline{psChartO4}{psChart4}
   \nput{0}{psChartO4}{Andet}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not very good; if I change the unit from `4cm` to `2cm`, the pie chart does occur but it is printed at the bottom left corner of the page (assuming I use `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg yes I know but I figured once you got it visible you'd be able to further tweak the coordinates and scale:-)

Comment: Good point; I tweaked the coordiates to get it right. (See my updated question.)

Answer (score 4):

For this case, it will be easier if we put the `\psset{unit=<length>}` after `\pspicture`. If you put it before `\pspicture` then the coordinates of `\pspicture` must be expressed with *bad* numbers and you will probably be unable to show grid with `showgrid` beautifully.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.2,-2.8)(4,2.7)
    \psset
    {
        unit=2cm,
        nodesepA=5pt,
        nodesepB=-5pt,
    }
    \psChart[
        userColor={blue!60,yellow!60,green!60,red!60},
        chartNodeO=1.25,
        shadow=true,
        shadowsize=5pt,
    ]{1082, 1572, 2336, 643}{}{}
    \rput(psChartI1){\SI{1082}{\square\km}}
    \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
    \nput{0}{psChartO1}{Rism. med}
    \rput(psChartI2){\SI{1572}{\square\km}}
    \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
    \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Rism. uden}
    \rput(psChartI3){\SI{2336}{\square\km}}
    \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
    \nput{270}{psChartO3}{Skov m.m.}
    \rput(psChartI4){\SI{643}{\square\km}}
    \ncline{psChartO4}{psChart4}
    \nput{0}{psChartO4}{Andet}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]